# PHP - spl_autoload_register Not Working with `namespace` and `use`

Tags: php

I am learning and trying to understand the use of `namespace` and `use` in PHP. I also use the `spl_autoload_register` as mention on the [php.net documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). I'm still confusing on using it and get an error.

I have 2 files on my tutorials folder:

1. php_oop.php
2. tutor.php

**php_oop.php**

```
<?php
namespace php_oop;

class php_oop 
{
    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function get(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**tutor.php**

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    var_dump($class_name);
    include $class_name . '.php';
    // include 'php_oop.php';
});

use php_oop;

$tutor = new php_oop('My Name');
echo $tutor->get();
```

**Output**

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'php_oop' has no
>   effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\oop\tutor.php on line 9
>       string(7) "php_oop" 
>       Fatal error: Class 'php_oop' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\oop\tutor.php on line 11

May I know how to use it correctly?

Comment: The first letter of the class name must be capital.

Comment: That's only a stylistic thing, @Nidhi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use` isn't like an `import`. You must `use` *every class you're using*, **not every namespace**. For your example, it would be:

```
use php_oop\php_oop;
```

which would import the `php_oop` *class* from the `php_oop` *namespace*.

See [the documentation for importing namespaces](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for more information and useful tips.

(side effect: The `$class_name` passed to `spl_autoload_register`'s callback contains the *full name of the class* including namespace. For your autoloader to load your class properly, you will either need to change your autoloader code or move your `php_oop.php` file to a folder named `php_oop` to match the namespace it comes from.)

Comment: Thanks for the details. I managed to get it by creating a folder like you suggest. If I want to change my autoloader code, do I need to manually assign the file name like `include 'php_oop.php';`

Comment: No, because that wouldn't be much of an autoloader ;). You would probably want to `explode` by `\` or something and take the last string in the resulting array if you *really* wanted to do something like that. But keeping an organized folder structure by namespace is better for collisions' sake and conforms more to standards.

Comment: I want to reconfirm regarding the namespace, does it have to be the same as our file name

Comment: Your file name should be the name of your *class*. The folders leading up to your filename should match the namespace. For example, if your class name is `App\Models\User`, you would mane an `App` directory, a `Models` directory in `App`, and `User.php` in `App/Models`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: searched 30 mins and finally this worked thanks. :-)